# Listener window.onMessage.listen not working in flutter web app. Between firebase service worker and web application

Tags: flutter, service-worker

I can't communicate with my flutter web app from the firebase service worker javascript. Everything works except this listener:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  html.window.onMessage.listen((event) {
    if (event.data['type'] == 'notificationclick') {
      var params = event.data['data'];
      var param1 = params['param1'];
      var param2 = params['param2'];
      print(param1);
      print(param2);
    }
  });
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

The function that is executed when a browser notification is clicked is this:

```
async function handleNotificationClick(event) {
   var allClients = await clients.matchAll({includeUncontrolled: true});
   var currentClient;
   for (var i = 0; i < allClients.length; i++) {
      var client = allClients[i];
      
      if (client['url'].indexOf(event.notification.data['link']) >= 0) {
         client.postMessage(
           {
              type: 'notificationclick',
              data: {
                 param1: 'example1',
                 param2: 'example2',
            }
         });
         client.focus();
         currentClient = client;
         break;
      }
   }
   if (currentClient == null || currentClient == 'undefined') {
      clients.openWindow(event.notification.data['link']);
   }
   event.notification.close();
}
```

Both focus and openWindow work correctly, but the web app does not listen to the message